# The system is listing one new favorite that is not mine

Tags: support, status-bydesign

When I logged in one minute ago, it appeared that I have one new favourite.

But I haven't logged in in the last 24 hours:

> visited        85 days, 1 consecutive

and it is supposed that it was my favorite 10 hours ago

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This means there was a new answer (or an edit) to a question you favorited.

see:

["Journaling" or "transactions" design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359624/journaling-or-transactions-design-pattern/3399723#3399723)

Comment: in the "added" tab the dates are those of last answers too, I suppose. Thanks and sorry!